# How to adjust Winamp (MilkDrop) preset appearance frequency?

Tags: windows-7, winamp

I just installed the Winamp 5.63, and I have a few questions:
The second question:
Is it possible in the MilkDrop visualizations to set how frequently a preset appears depending on its rating?
In the MilkDrop settings it is implied that a preset's appearance frequency depends on its rating. The rating is from 0 to 5, with rating 0 meaning that a preset is never shown. From this, one may conclude that a preset with rating 5 is shown most frequently. I rated the presets, yet the player still shows me a lot of presets with ratings of 1 and 2, and not so frequently those with rating 5. Is it possible at all to change that rating-frequency dependence? 
Thank you!

Comment: You can view the rating for a preset by pressing F6. See if your ratings have actually been saved properly.

Comment: Hi, Karan! Thanks for your help. The ratings are saved correctly, and yet the appearance frequency does not seem to depend on them at all.

Comment: I stopped using Winamp a long time ago, so I'm a bit fuzzy about the MilkDrop settings. Maybe you can try contacting the author [Ryan Geiss](http://www.geisswerks.com/contact.html) directly?

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. I'll give that a try. What music player are you using now? I desperately need a decent player with awesome visualizations. A lot of stress lately :-)

Comment: I use foobar2000 which is awesome, but I don't care much about visualisations any more. fb2k should support 3rd party vis plugins I guess and should also be able to run Winamp vis plugins. Edit: Check out [Shpeck](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=59388).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Karan. Visualization-wise it does not seem any better than the Winamp itself, so I will probably stick with the latter. I'll see if I can tweak the frequency.

Comment: Yup, but IMO it is just a better overall music player and as I said above, Shpeck will enable you to use MilkDrop with foobar. Anyway, even if you switch you'd still need to fix the issue, probably with help from Geiss.

Comment: Karan, could you please elaborate on "better overall"? I've sent a letter to Mr. Geiss. Let's see what he suggests. I used to use VLC player, and it also can run MilkDrop through Project M, though it apparently can not run it in full screen and neither MilkDrop controls are available. You can not rate presets, for example.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "better overall" - Honestly, this thread is neither the place for it, nor would I attempt to answer this since software preferences are often quite subjective. I'm sure for every point I make, some Winamp lover will refute the same. :) Best you try it out for yourself (a portable install is possible), and make up your own mind.